# Covering a PrimeNG p-table with a blurry overlay

Tags: css, angular, overlay, primeng

I'm working on an improvement to an Angular webpage. It currently looks like this:

[image: Base webpage]

I'm tasked with adding a light blue overlay that blurs the data in the table based on a boolean value. It's supposed to look like this:

[image: Expected result]

I'm using a p-table from the PrimeNG library of components (PrimeNG 14.0.0 on Angular 14.1.0). My main issue is showing this component covering the totality of the table content (ignoring the table headers if possible), and having the text aligned in the middle of the component. I've managed to blur the data in the table already with this class:

```
.blur-cover {
    filter: blur(3px);
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

but the blue area with the text in it covering the content is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `p-table` in a div add the class `blur-cover` to it

```
<div class="blur-cover">
... your p-table here
  <p class="text-container">
    some long text
  </p>
</div>
```

and use css add blur backgroup to the tbody and adjust the position of the text in your style.css

```
.blur-cover {
  position: relative;
}
.blur-cover tbody {
  filter: blur(3px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.blur-cover .text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo-py3qdy?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: Thanks jitender. I've just learnt a bit of position with top and left :)